# What's the size of the newest AppIcon for Xcode 8 and how to get them in an easier way?

Tags: ios10, xcode8

I just updated my Xcode to Version 8, the AppIcon I built before (for Xcode 7) are not useful anymore. And I have tried many online AppIcon generators but no one can create a full set of the AppIcon. The new version of AppIcon set is as below:

[image]

Besides, I have searched the [official doc](https://developer.apple.com/ios/human-interface-guidelines/graphics/app-icon/) of AppIcon, the explanation and descriptions are all about the previous version. There is even no doc describing the icon size of iPhone 7. Below is a table in the Apple doc:

[image]

Anyone know the size of the whole set of AppIcon? Anyway to generate them expediently?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you see 20pt 2x it should be 40x40, 60pt 2x 120, and 60 pt 3x 180, you just need to multiply the pt value by the x value.

To generate all the sizes I recommend using Inkscape which is excellent at resizing images.

Answer (score 2):

Create your 1024x1024 icon, install imagemagick on your mac and run this script

```
#!/bin/bash

convert icon1024.png -resize 40x40 icon20ptx2.png
convert icon1024.png -resize 60x60 icon20ptx3.png

convert icon1024.png -resize 58x58 icon29ptx2.png
convert icon1024.png -resize 87x87 icon29ptx3.png

convert icon1024.png -resize 80x80 icon40ptx2.png
convert icon1024.png -resize 120x120 icon40ptx3.png

convert icon1024.png -resize 120x120 icon60ptx2.png
convert icon1024.png -resize 180x180 icon60ptx3.png
```